# How to drag & drop several files to elaborate each file in a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, script, drag-and-drop

I'm using Dolphin in a KDE Plasma 5 Desktop Environment. Here I wrote a bash script, which can elaborate exactly ONE file, when I drag a file from Dolphin and drop it on a ".desktop" defined script with an icon, which then executes e.g. `/home/user/scripts/list_all_drags.sh %f`.

This works with such one file.
Now I would like to drag several selected files from Dolphin into the script and the script should elaborate its procedures for each file entry. This doesn't work, though I used `%F` for multiple files instead of `%f` for a single file.

What happens is, that several terminal windows are opened, one for each file entry. What I need is the code to be executed in ONE script, for each file entry dropped, without opening several terminal windows, but the first one.
Exactly, the "loop" to start or to execute the commands with the dropped files, without any more key press.

I don't know how to handle the `%F` parameter value in my script.

Comment: Works for me as advertized, I get the separate scripts only if I replace `%F` with `%f`. How do you create the .desktop?

Comment: When you right click on menu symbol left side down, then chose "edit applications" (first entry), then you'll see the KDE menu structure. Here you can select a group and within the group you can then select "New element" from menu bar. This is already a ".desktop" base file, which you can adopt for your needs.

Comment: ...
name it, chose an icon and select the program or script, you want to execute, then you'll need to "Save" (Left item in menu bar) to create this new ".desktop" file, which is named as you have named it.
This file is saved at: /home/user/.local/share/plasma_icons

Comment: Yes, I know, but this doesn't create an icon on the desktop... So where do you drag your files? Also, if you select several files in Dolphin, right click, Open with... and select your app, do they get all processed together or do they still get a script instance each?

Comment: When you finished the new element with "Save", then you can find it by typing the name, when you launch KDE (Plasma) menu. Then you can drag and drop the new item (icon) onto your desktop or into a task line.

Comment: Still one single execution.  Did you try the "Open with>"?

Comment: No, I did not. That was not the purpose of my aim. I simply want to have executed my script for every single marked (selected) file as it is easily possible to drag and drop selected files from one location to another.

Comment: Yes, but it should be the same behavior, because you'll be using the same .desktop file. If you get a single script call that way; the .desktop is OK and the problem is elsewhere. Just as matter of debugging the problem, you know...

Answer (score 0):

I think, I've found the correct answer, especially how to handle the multiple parameters with %F.

First I select my entries (files) in a filemanager. Second I drag all these marked files onto my script icon and drop them on that icon. Inside this script which is executed with "/home/user/scripts/myscript.sh %F" there is a routine, which elaborates all selected file entries.

Though I'm not sure how many parameters (files) could be mass selected and elaborated then, this routine here helps me to count up all single parameters greater than 0 (which are my selected, my marked files):

`while (( $# > 0 ))    # or [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    echo "$1"
    shift
done`

Instead of "echo $1" I can say

`file = $1`

and then call my subroutine where I work with $file

Special thanks to this post: How to handle more than 10 parameters in a shell